# Single Workflow Template for Different Environments

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to publish a single re-usable Github [starter workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/creating-starter-workflows-for-your-organization#creating-a-starter-workflow) template to my organisation which can be used for multiple environments (let's say "acc" and "prod").

The template workflow works well; I can use `concurrency.group`, `jobs{}.environment`, and `on` keys to control the environment deployment for the first environment (acc). I'd like to control the "prod" environment deploy in a separate workflow file, which would be identical, but with different values for the above (`prod`, and `on: master`).

Having the single template file filled with `FILL ME IN` for these seems like the wrong thing, yet I can't find a better way to do it. Actions don't seem appropriate either, or am I missing something?

For example, the template file has:

```
...
concurrency:
  group: FILL ME IN
...
on: [push]
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - FILL ME IN
...
jobs:
...

  deploy:
    needs: build_and_test
    environment: FILL ME IN

...
```

I feel like there's a better way?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm trying to avoid publishing another re-usable workflow, since I'm near the 4 level limit already.